# Mockito - How to ask for a Mock of Java Lambda Function

Tags: java, lambda, mockito

I have a java lambda function in a test class

```
public class Blabla {

private Function<String, TypeA> forStringReturnTypeAResult;

// other code incl. getter/setter
}
```

But I would now like to get a Mock object to mock behaviour of the above lambda function object

```
public class BlaBlaTest {

      Function<String,TypeA> forStringReturnTypeAResult = mock(Function.class);

     // Other test code
}
```

The above code compiles, but clearly the typing is Raw (not generic). I cannot seem to think of any way (without explicitly casting) I can infer the types. Perhaps, this is one of the typical brain freeze periods :(.

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Regards,

Comment: @Kayaman      I need to mock that because lambda guarantees an input/output  contract - and the implementation can be anything as long as I/O contract is correct. Because it's part of a legacy code that interacts with database a lot, I am testing it in a way that partially mocks certain service calls without getting wrapped into runtime initialization. In this way, I am simply mocking what's going to be returned via the legacy service without actually calling it. And it's better than writing no unit test at all.

Comment: But why do you need to use Mockito for that? You can just write `forStringReturnTypeAResult = x -> someA`

Comment: @Thilo         perhaps that's the brain freeze point - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can work with annotations to mock types with generic parameters:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BlaBlaTest {

    @Mock
    public Function<String,TypeA> functionMock;

}
```

Or you could create an extra method which returns the mocked function with generics, but you will get warnings (which you could suppress with @suppressWarnings)

```
public class BlaBlaTest {

    Function<String,TypeA> forStringReturnTypeAResult = functionMock();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> Function<String, T> functionMock() {
        return mock(Function.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: from the question - *The above code compiles, but clearly the typing is Raw (not generic)*, what have you improved?

Comment: The solution with the annotations is not 'raw' anymore, but generic.
The second solutions makes sure the 'raw' part is only in one place, which is still better than having to suppress every use of the mock...